# MacOS Notes App: Font keeps changing

Tags: macos, font, notes.app

I think it’s bad enough that you can’t properly change the default font (not just the size) in the Notes App.

I have got used to selecting all and changing the font manually. However, if I press Return at the end of a line, and wait more than a second, the font reverts to the default, rather than the font of the previous line. If I’m quick enough, the font is the same as the previous line.

How can I get the notes app to stick to the chosen font?

Comment: I opened a Note and selected a line. I then went to the menubar and clicked on Format. This brings up a pane that has Show Fonts. I click that option and a panel appears with all the fonts listed. I click on the font of my choice and the selected line will change to that font. it stays that way until I change it back.  What are you doing differently?

Comment: @jmh At the end of the line I press `return`. The next line should be the same font as the previous one. If I type immediately, the font is good, but if I wait about a second before typing, the font of the new line reverts to the default.